# mDisplayList is not valid

Tags: android, fragment

I've problem with... I don't really recognise, what cause the problem...
LogCat is giving me such error:

[image: from LogCat]

What I can say...
Action in app is going in that way:

> 1. I'm creating Intent chooser, putting to chooser options from packageManager.queryIntentActivities ... that's all
> 2. I'm getting photo from camera or another app
> 3. I'm returning to app, and at this moment I'm getting errors.

I can add, that getting a photo is induces from one of two fragments which are on activity.

What I can say is that sometimes after I'm moving back to my app, app is stucking in loading.

Please let me know if you'll need more Information.
Any tip for searching will be very helpful (I found nothing about that in the Internet)

Edit:
Fragment which calls for image:

```
public class AddAmbajFragment extends AbstractFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button addImageButton;
    private Uri outputFileUri;

    public AddAmbajFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_ambaj, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        assignViews();
        setListeners();
    }

    public void assignViews(){
        addImageButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add_ambaj_camera_button);
    }

    public void setListeners(){
        addImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void changeView(FragmentPlaceEnum fragmentPlaceEnum, FragmentEnum fragmentEnum){
        if(changeFragmentEventListener!=null)
            changeFragmentEventListener.onFragmenChange(fragmentPlaceEnum, fragmentEnum);
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        openImageIntent();
    }

    private void openImageIntent() {

        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "AmbajePhotos" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        final String fname = "img_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.add_ambaj_select_source));

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try {
        if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode == 1)
            {
                final boolean isCamera;
                if(data == null)
                {
                    isCamera = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if(action == null)
                    {
                        isCamera = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

                    Uri selectedImageUri;
                    if (isCamera) {
                        selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                        File imgFile = new File(selectedImageUri.getPath());
                        if (imgFile.exists()) {

                            Bitmap myBitmap = getScaledBitmap(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), 800, 800);

                            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.add_ambaj_image_view);
                            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                        }
                    } else {
                        selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                        File imgFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri));

                        if (imgFile.exists()) {

                            Bitmap myBitmap = getScaledBitmap(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), 800, 800);

                            ImageView myImage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.add_ambaj_image_view);
                            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        }
                    }


            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.w("KKK", "Error: "+e.toString());
        }
    }


    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            if("content".equals(contentUri.getScheme())) {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            else{
                return contentUri.getPath();
            }


        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String picturePath, int width, int height) {
        BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);

        int inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(sizeOptions, width, height);

        sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        sizeOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);
    }

    private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Main activity which contains fragment

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends Activity implements ChangeFragmentEventListener {
    AbstractFragment menuFragment;
    AbstractFragment contentFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);
        assignViews();
        setListeners();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmenChange(FragmentPlaceEnum fragmentPlaceEnum, FragmentEnum fragmentEnum) {

        AbstractFragment newFragment = null;
        if(fragmentEnum.equals(FragmentEnum.MAIN_WALL_FRAGMENT))
            newFragment = new MainWallFragment();
        else if(fragmentEnum.equals(FragmentEnum.GROUPS_FRAGMENT))
            newFragment = new GroupsFragment();
        else if(fragmentEnum.equals(FragmentEnum.NOTIFICATIONS_FRAGMENT))
            newFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
        else if (fragmentEnum.equals(FragmentEnum.ADD_AMBAJ_FRAGMENT))
            newFragment = new AddAmbajFragment();

        contentFragment = newFragment;

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
        if(fragmentPlaceEnum.equals(FragmentPlaceEnum.MAIN_ACTIVITY_CONTENT))
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content_fragment, newFragment);
        else if(fragmentPlaceEnum.equals(FragmentPlaceEnum.MAIN_ACTIVITY_MENU))
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_menu_fragment, newFragment);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
       transaction.commit();
    }

    private void assignViews(){

        menuFragment = (AbstractFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_menu_fragment);
        contentFragment = (AbstractFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_content_fragment);
    }

    private void setListeners(){
        menuFragment.setChangeFragmentEventListener(this);
        contentFragment.setChangeFragmentEventListener(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: are you printing that line?

Comment: does your application crash?

Comment: Not when I'm getting errors. Sometimes it crashes after goint back to app, but there is no action from application at that time.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, "sometimes it crashes" I would bet you are not using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState`  This is just a hunch.  It would be helpful if you posted your code as well as the log; To check if this is part of the problem, on your device, go to settings>developer options> and check "don't keep activities..  if your devices doesn't show developer options :http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //save things

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        //restore things

    }
```

**Example of an AsyncTask for Image Resizing**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;



public class ImageResizerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

    Bitmap mBitmap;
    String filePath;
    Context mContext;
    YourActivity mCallBack;
    //ProgressDialog pd;

    public ImageResizerTask(Context context, String path,
            YourActivity callBack) {

        mContext = context;
        filePath = path;
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        mCallBack = callBack;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resize(mBitmap);
        return mBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

        bitmap.recycle();
        mCallBack.onImageResized(filePath);

    }


    private void resize(Bitmap tmp) {

        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Log.v("TMPBMP",
                "temp bmp width:" + tmp.getWidth() + " height:"
                        + tmp.getHeight());

        if (tmp.getWidth() < tmp.getHeight()) {
            final int width = (int) (1f * tmp.getWidth() / tmp.getHeight() * 500);

            final int height = 500;
            final Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, width, height,
                    false);
            final int leftOffset = (bitmap.getWidth() - scaled.getWidth()) / 2;
            final int topOffset = 0;
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, leftOffset, topOffset, null);
        } else {
            final int width = 500;
            final int height = (int) (1f * tmp.getHeight() / tmp.getWidth() * 500);
            ;
            final Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, width, height,
                    false);
            final int leftOffset = 0;
            final int topOffset = (bitmap.getHeight() - scaled.getHeight()) / 2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, leftOffset, topOffset, null);
        }

        FileOutputStream outStream;

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            try {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: That's right - I'm not saving state, when I'm changing activity to for example camera... I've made short test at this moment, only what I can say, that on changing events between apps are always onPause/onResume (never onDestroy), and nothing changes here when app crashes. I'll try to make some saving state.
I'm adding to the main post image call method, which I'm using.

Comment: again, please post your code and your logs.  Not that the OS can kill your activity when its low on memory, and then when you return from camera you will have null pointers

Comment: There are logs (they are big, so I put them to another server):
Filtered by application : http://speedy.sh/2XRFC/app-filter-logcat.txt
Without filter : http://speedy.sh/ecSpY/full-logcat.txt
Which part of code do you need?

Comment: I'd like to see the activity code that has the 'mDisplayList'  it looks like it is indeed your app running out of memory as right before the 'not valid message you will note your log says: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 18179K/18840K, paused 29ms, total 29ms  that means you have 4% memory left and garbage collection is happening

Comment: I've put it into first post. Fragment which is calling for image, and activity which is containing fragment. One of them should contains view, which causes error.

Comment: I don't see any reference to mDisplayList anywhere, but as a side note, you might want to move the bitmap scaling to an AsyncTask so it can be done in the background and not on the same thread as your UI i'll try to post an example as an edit

Comment: Thak you for AsyncTask code - it works great. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem with app crash. I'll try to review the code and write saving state methods. Thank you for trying to help me.